# Regular expression to match an ldap connection string

Tags: php, regex, ldap

I need to extract information from an LDAP connection string like this one:

```
ldap://uid=adminuser,dc=example,c=com:secret@ldap.example.com/dc=basePath,dc=example,c=com
```

I want to use a regular expression that will extract each token for me and place it in an array. I tried some regex expression and the best I got was this:

```
/(\w+)\:\/\/(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(:([^\:\@]+))?@)?([^\/]+)((\/[^#]*)?(#(.*))?)/
```

But unfortunately, when I execute it in PHP, I get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ldap://uid=adminuser,dc=example,c=com:secret@ldap.example.com/dc=basePath,dc=example,c=com
    [1] => ldap
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => uid=adminuser,dc=example,c=com:secret@ldap.example.com
    [7] => /dc=basePath,dc=example,c=com
    [8] => /dc=basePath,dc=example,c=com
)
```

Can anybody help me so that I can correctly extract each part of the connection string?

Thanks

Comment: Which language are you using? Could you edit your question to show the expected result for your sample string? Is the order and number of parts variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` seems quite inadequate to pick up an LDAP string containing `=` and other characters.

In general you should not try to parse URLs yourself with regex. Instead, use the standard library function [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

This gives:

```
array(5) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "ldap"
  ["host"]=>
  string(16) "ldap.example.com"
  ["user"]=>
  string(30) "uid=adminuser,dc=example,c=com"
  ["pass"]=>
  string(6) "secret"
  ["path"]=>
  string(29) "/dc=basePath,dc=example,c=com"
}
```

Comment: WOW! That is way better than a regex:) Thanks a lot!